# Display "In progress" message while downloading an Excel file

Tags: excel, spring, jsp

I am building a Spring MVC application where on click of a link, I want some processing to be done in my controller. Controller will generate an Excel sheet based on processing and send this Excel sheet back to same JSP.

But since processing and downloading of file by controller takes some time, say around 30 seconds, I want to display an "in progress" window, or some kind of information to users so that they are well aware that downloading is taking place and user should wait. I tried the code below which shows the message but doesn't download the file:

```
function validateMyValues(value1, value2) 
{
    dialog = openWin("Please wait while downloading is in progress....");
    document.myform.action="getDbData";

    var data = 'value1='
                +value1+'&value2='
                +value2; 
    alert("Action1: " + document.myform.action);
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: document.myform.action,
        data: data,
        success: closeWin
    }); 
}

var myWindow;

function openWin(message) {
    var w = 200;
    var h = 200;
    var left = Number((screen.width/2)-(w/2));
    var top = Number((screen.height/2)-(h/2));

    myWindow = window.open("", "myWindow", 'width='+w+', height='+h+',   top='+top+', left='+left);
    myWindow.document.write(message);

}

function closeWin() {
   myWindow.close();
}
```

Below is my JSP link:

```
<a class="myClass1" href="javascript:validateMyValues('<%=value1%>','<%=value2%>')"><img src="./images/btn_valid.png" border="0" /></a>
```

And my controller code for downloading is:

```
    //flushing now the file to web page
FileInputStream fileIn = new FileInputStream(outputFile);
ServletOutputStream out = response.getOutputStream();

response.setContentType ("application/download");
response.setHeader ("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=\""+filename+"\"");
response.setHeader("Set-Cookie", "fileDownload=true; path=/");

byte[] outputByte = new byte[4096];

//copy binary content to output stream
while(fileIn.read(outputByte, 0, 4096) != -1)
{
    out.write(outputByte, 0, 4096);
}

fileIn.close();
out.flush();
out.close();

return null;
```

Only thing I require is to display the "in progress" message to user till the downloaded is complete.

Answer (score 0):

If the processing takes a while your option would be to stream results back to the client. Meaning sending back data while it's still being written in the output stream.

To do that you can use JDK 7 [PipedOutputStream](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/PipedOutputStream.html). For e.g.:

```
PipedOutputStream out = new PipedOutputStream();
PipedInputStream in = new PipedInputStream(out); 

executor.execute(new Runnable() {

    @Override
    public void run() {
        while(fileIn.read(outputByte, 0, 4096) != -1){
           out.write(outputByte, 0, 4096);
        }
    }
});

IOUtils.copy(in, response.getOutputStream());
```

Just note that it is highly recommended to do writing in a different thread, so make sure you have an instance of some executor.

> A piped output stream can be connected to a piped input stream to
>   create a communications pipe. The piped output stream is the sending
>   end of the pipe. Typically, data is written to a PipedOutputStream
>   object by one thread and data is read from the connected
>   PipedInputStream by some other thread. Attempting to use both objects
>   from a single thread is not recommended as it may deadlock the thread.
>   The pipe is said to be broken if a thread that was reading data bytes
>   from the connected piped input stream is no longer alive.

So what happens here is that your thread A writes data to piped output stream and thread B (which is a servlet) reads from it and sends it back to the client in chunks. This way your client will see a progress in the browser it self and you'll never get a timeout if job is taking long.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you Paulius for your response. I have tried this. The "download in progress" window is displayed but, once the file is downloaded, neither the "download in progress" is closed nor the file download save window appears on browser. :(

Comment: I've used below code in my controller: `
      ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(2);

   final PipedOutputStream out = new PipedOutputStream();
   final PipedInputStream in = new PipedInputStream(out); 

   executor.execute(new Runnable() {

       @Override
       public void run() {
        try
        {
         while(in.read(outputByte, 0, 4096) != -1){
             out.write(outputByte, 0, 4096);
            }
        }
        catch (IOException e) {
      // TODO Auto-generated catch block
      e.printStackTrace();
     }
       }
   });

Comment: remaining code from above comment:
   'IOUtils.copy(in, response.getOutputStream());
   
   in.close();
   out.flush();
   out.close();`

Comment: Can anyone please help here?